# n-ary groups references

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for online copies of

"Algebraic n-ary systems", SA Rusakov - Navuka i Tékhnika, Minsk, 1992

and

"Some applications of n-ary group theory", SA Rusakov - Belaruskaya navuka, Minsk, 1998

Do you know where to find them ?

Comment: Is there any reason you would expect online copies to exist?  You should either email Rusakov to ask if he has a copy or go to your university library (either they have it or they can obtain it via interlibrary loan).  I don't think asking on MO is likely to be effective.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think the books you are looking for can be found on the Web. But here is a book edited by Rusakov with an article by him and what seem to be his students and close colleagues. I hope you read Russian: http://free-books.dontexist.com/book/index.php?md5=8b32c468da0d44bb0e9339640fa275a5 although there are short English summaries. I doubt the book was translated into any other language.